# Java8 streams and typecasts

Tags: java, casting, java-8, java-stream

Can anybody explain to me why the following code is not working?

I was trying to get a feel for the new features of Java8 and solved the BerlinClock Kata. During this I had to parse a String in the format `"hh:mm:ss"` - I wanted to use streams and wrote the following piece of code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

private Integer[] parseTime (String time){
    Integer[] hhmmss = (Integer[]) Arrays.stream(time.split(":"))
                                         .map(s->Integer.parseInt(s)).toArray();
    return hhmmss;
}
```

but the runtime system (I think) is complaining that the explicit type cast `(Integer[])` cannot be done.

As far as I understand it the `Arrays.stream(time.split(":"))` part returns a `Stream<String>`, then `map(s->Integer.parseInt(s))` converts this to `Stream<Integer>`, then `toArray()` produces an `Object[]`. Now a type cast to `Integer[]` should be possible as the intermediate stream was had an `Integer` type-parameter.

Note that I know how to solve this problem without type cast by using

```
int[] hhmmss= Arrays.stream(time.split(":")
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

and changing the type signature accordingly to `int[] parseTime`.
But I do not understand why there is a problem in the type-cast.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the first case, [`Stream#map()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method will give you a `Stream<Integer>`, and then [`Stream#toArray()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray--) returns an `Object[]`, which you need to cast to `Integer[]`. But at runtime, this cast may fail, if internally an `Object[]` is created instead of an `Integer[]`, which is the case here. The source code of `toArray()` method for this stream looks like this:

```
@Override
public final Object[] toArray() {
    return toArray(Object[]::new);
}
```

And you can't cast an `Object[]` to an `Integer[]` reference.

You can solve this issue by using [`Stream#toArray(IntFunction)`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) instead, and then you wouldn't need a cast:

```
private Integer[] parseTime (String time){
    Integer[] hhmmss = Arrays.stream(time.split(":"))
                    .map(s->Integer.valueOf(s))
                    .toArray(Integer[]::new);
    return hhmmss;
}
```

In second case however, [`Stream#mapToInt()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) method gives you an `IntStream`, and [`IntStream#toArray()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray--) returns an `int[]`, and hence no casting required there.

Comment: Instead of `.map(s->Integer.valueOf(s))`, I think you can also do `.map(Integer::valueOf);` :P